# Building PJSIP: giving error for Make command on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pjsip

I want to use the pjsip library in ubuntu 13.10 and tried the steps given in getting started page of pjsip.org

I tried to build the pjsip lib by using the following sequence of commands and also I edited the config_site.h to have the `#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO` line in it. Also I installed video4linux2 and ffmpeg before running these commands

```
cd pjproject
./configure
make dep
make
```

After I ran the last command I got following error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/vk/pjproject/pjsip/build'
make[2]: `../lib/libpjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vk/pjproject/pjsip/build'
make -f /home/vk/pjproject/build/rules.mak APP=PJSUA2_LIB app=pjsua2-lib ../lib/libpjsua2-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/vk/pjproject/pjsip/build'
.pjsua2-lib-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.depend:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vk/pjproject/pjsip/build'
make[1]: *** [libpjsua2-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vk/pjproject/pjsip/build'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

So could anyone please help me in resolving this error?

Answer (score 7):

Just run following commands on your PJSIP directory path using Terminal/Command line Interface.

```
make distclean

make clean

make realclean
```

Important one to run at last,

```
find . -name "*.depend" -exec rm {} \;
```

After that you want to configure and build your PJSIP Project using,

> ./configure-iphone      OR ./configure-android
>
> make dep && make clean && make

I thought, this will help you to solve this problem!

Answer (score 3):

Try to install gcc-c++, it fixed trouble for me in the same case

Comment: sudo apt-get install g++ and then deleting the pjproject folder, download it and finally run configure and make commands did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

Just copy .pjsua2-test-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.depend to .pjsua2-lib-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.depend and replace all occurences of -test- with -lib- in that file. Run make again.

Comment: Hi, when I am building pjsip for android , I am specifying TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a but its creating .so file under  project/libs/armeabi .