# PJSip not building on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, voip, pjsip

I am trying to follow the below tutorial to get the demo code working. https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone
I am struck at the following command : $ make dep && make clean && make.  The Voip folder contains the PSip folder. Below is my Project folder structure: [image]

I am getting the below error:

```
build.mak:2: /Users/Documents/Projects/VOIP: No such file or directory
build.mak:2: App/PSip/version.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `App/PSip/version.mak'.  Stop.
```

I am trying to develop a VOIP App with an Open source Library. Please suggest any other better option to implement a VOIP App which is free and Open source.

Comment: PJSIP is an effective open source library for VoIP App. Did you follow all steps in the PJSIP build instructions for iOS? try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46336336/4692211)

Comment: @NandhaKumar, After I got ahead to the above step. I am struck with 330 Build errors, something like this: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pjmedia_port_destroy", referenced from:
      _app_destroy in pjsua_app.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).        I tried googling and found out that the libraries are not built for arm64 architecture. So can you help me with how to fix this issue. Where can I set the architecture to arm64

Comment: you want to build the libraries for target devices like Mac OS(X86_64), iOS(armv7/arm64) like that. If the libraries are mismatching with your devices, then it'll show the errors like above. so sure you wrongly built the libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. it was a space in one of my folder name that was causing the issue.